Area of the wet part of a horizontal cylinder
So, my math teacher gave me an interesting problem on mensuration.
Given, a cylinder of Height $H$ and radius $r$ is filled with water upto height h. Then the cylinder is pushed and it lies down horizontally. Given condition is $H>2h$. Find out the area of the wet part when the cylinder is lying down.

My teacher said it could be done if someone knew a basic concept. I thought about it for a long time, but I could not find a way to approach it. I don't know if this problem is easy and if I am just too dumb, but I hope someone helps.

Try conserving the volume

The water mass (so volume) conservation is a must condition. Then what you need is the volume formula from any book.

(Area of water surface that touches the lid)$×H=πr^2h$. Mind you this will only allow to find the area of the surface that touches the lid, which is a segment

The $H>2h$ part means the water-line is below the diameter of the cylinder ends. Finding the area is then surely a basic trigonometric calculation (or Pythagoras would work probably). Then it is just a matter of eliminating $r$ from the formula.

I'm borrowing Roland F's diagram of the laid down cylinder end and distance z between the water surface and the centre of the cylinder.
Area of sector with angle $\theta$ at centre is
$\pi$$R^2$ * ($\theta$/2$\pi$) = ($\theta$$R^2$)/2.
Area of triangular part on top is
zRsin($\theta$/2) where z = Rcos($\theta$/2)
so Area of the cylinder end below water is
A_end = ($\theta$$R^2$)/2 - $R^2$cos($\theta$/2)sin($\theta$/2) = ($\theta$$R^2$)/2 - $R^2$sin($\theta$)/2.
The Volume of water
V = $\pi$$R^2$h = HA_end
Area of the wet parts of the cylinder is therefore
2A_end + RH$\theta$.
The tricky part is solving for theta,...
$\theta$ - sin($\theta$) = 2$\pi$h/H
May have to do it numerically.

Is there a reason why you can't use MathJax?

@DavidK Just never used it before. I've formatted the equations to make it neater.

FWIW I wrote a simple c function to calculate the inverse of x minus sin x here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Inverse-of-x-minus-sin-x-/tree/main.
